# How to make jQuery autocomplete update when database is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Right after I create a new artist in my database, upon visiting my new review page, I want to be able to see that artist in the autocomplete options, but currently I can not. I have an artist field in my review form with the id artistField. For some reason it seems like on my heroku application, the artists are only updated in the autocomplete when I do another push. Why is this? Here is the function I'm using (it has embedded ruby).

To be more clear, I expect it to be available after a page refresh, so not immediately (without refresh, with ajax). Also when I test locally, it only seems to update each time I make an edit and then resave my javascript file...

```
$(function() {
      var availableTags;
      availableTags = <%= Artist.all.collect{|artist| artist.name} %>;
      //alert(availableTags);
      $("#artistField").autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
      });
});
```

Comment: `availableTags` is rendered server side at page load to be a static list at the client.  You'll need to reassign the value of `availableTags` via Ajax or reload the page.

Comment: @intracept reloading the page does not do the trick

Comment: Really?  How odd.  But to see your update, you'll want to use Ajax behind your autocomplete.  Take a look at the documentation for using it with Ajax.  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp